# MySQL get records by quarters

Tags: php, mysql

Have problem to returning results from MySQL by quarters.

Mysql:
`id`, `start_datetime`, `end_datetime` and more columns.

I need to return records by start_datetime (for example it's - `2016-03-05 20:12:22` | MySQL column format is DateTime). How can I write MySQL query to display that record in a specific quarter?

I was searching a lot but didn't find anything that would work fo me: I tested this:

```
SELECT * FROM appointments 
WHERE id_user = 80 
AND DATE_SUB(start_datetime, INTERVAL 1 QUARTER) 
AND hash = 'completed'
```

But it's not working correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the results for quarter 1:

```
SELECT * FROM appointments 
WHERE id_user = 80 
AND QUARTER(start_datetime) = 1 
AND hash = 'completed'
```

Change the "1" to 2, 3, or 4 to get the other quarters

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to get all the data based on quarter inMySql or WordPress.

Note : visited is the datetime column into the table

`QUARTER(your date)` will give you the current quarter.

> **Previous Quarter**

`SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE QUARTER(visited) = QUARTER(curdate() - INTERVAL 1 quarter)`

---

> **Current Quarter**

`SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE QUARTER(visited) = QUARTER(curdate())`